# Two products creating onclick button instead of one

Tags: magento-1.9

Once **guest user** click on button we are creating Product Programtically  but issue is every time we click on button its creating 2 products instead of one.

**form**

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', 
 array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'),
 'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>" id="ajaxlogin-login-form">
```

**controllers**

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
{       
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 
        $product->setDescription('what ever you need here');

        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);      

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

full form code : http://pasted.co/d5b63b52

**Edit**

Once i removed this code from **"form"** : `id="ajaxlogin-login-form` , than its creating only one product, but after that once guest click on "save design" button, it will redirect to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form', true);
            jQuery("#ajaxlogin-login-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ajaxLoginForm.validator.validate()) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').attr('action'),
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('There is some error saving your design.');
        });
    }
});
            //]]>
        </script>
```

With this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form', true);
                jQuery("#ajaxlogin-login-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (ajaxLoginForm.validator.validate()) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').attr('action'),
            }).done(function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert('There is some error saving your design.');
            });
        }
return false;
    });
                //]]>
            </script>
```

Comment: please check `edit part in question`

Comment: your form is being submitted twice

Comment: please tell how i can fix the issue ?

Comment: `onSubmit="return false;"` add this to form tag

Comment: sorry buddy, still 2 products only creating......